# CSS Style coming for body element and not for header section when both configured

Tags: css, background-color

[image]

In this case body element is getting the color linen but h1 element is not getting lightblue.
Can anyone please explain me this as I am new to CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your semicolons are not ending the CSS statements. You need to make sure to run code through a linter for syntax errors before posting. Here's what it should look like:

```
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: Just to further this answer, the semicolon after the `body` css (after the closing bracket) is actually disabling the next statement, in this case the `h1` css, which is why you're seeing the error